# How to get alternate value of sub tags and then parent tags through xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a below XML structure, Title tag is the parent tag while Micro tag is the child tag, In output I want the value of first Micro tag i.e 'K' then first text value of Title tag i.e. ',' then again value of second Micro tag i.e. E and then again second text value of Title tag i.e. ', and' and so on.
     I am using this input xml file .

```
 <Head>
 <Title>
 <Micro>K</Micro>, <Micro>
 <Ind>L</Ind>
 <Ind>X</Ind>E</Micro>, and <Micro>S</Micro> I</Title>
 <Title>
 <Micro>M</Micro>
 <Ind>W</Ind>
 <Ind>G</Ind> O</Title><Head>
```

Output Should be:

```
    <Heading topic="K,E, and S I"/>
    <Heading topic="M O"/>
```

Comment: What have you tried? Also, your input XML isn't XML. Can you include the XSLT you've attempted to use, and describe how it wasn't performing correctly?

Comment: I have used this code :<xsl:variable name="onlyTitle">
   <xsl:apply-templates select="Title/text()" />
   </xsl:variable>
   <xsl:variable name="microtitle">
    <xsl:when test="Title[child::Micro]">
     <xsl:apply-templates select="Title/descendant::Micro/text()"/>    
    </xsl:when>
    
   </xsl:variable>.

Comment: Please include the _entire_ stylesheet (or, if it's too long, a selection of relevant templates) and edit it into the original post, do not post code in comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this should work for you:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:for-each select="Head/Title">
    <Heading>
        <xsl:attribute name="topic">
            <xsl:for-each select="Micro/text() | text()">
                <xsl:value-of select="translate(., '&#10;', '')"/>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </Heading>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note:
Your source XML shouldn't really contain line feeds within the Title element, when the element contains meaningful text nodes.

In addition, I had to fix the ending Head tag.